# Epilog outside the plotting area

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm trying to represent the projection of a point on the axes of a plot.

```
plot1 = ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"][
  Plot[{x^2, Line[{{5, 0}, {5, 10}}]}, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 100}, FrameStyle -> {{Blue, Red}, {Black, Black}},
    BaseStyle -> 15], 
  Plot[100 x^4, {x, 0, 10}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log", Frame -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 10^6}, FrameStyle -> Red, PlotStyle -> Red], 
  "AxesSides" -> "TwoY"]

annotation[x_, y0_, y1_, txt_] := 
 With[{dy = .33}, {Dashed, Gray, Line[{{x, y0}, {x, y1}}], 
   Text[txt, {x, y0 - dy}]}]

poi = {{5, "t1"}};

plot2 = Show[plot1, FrameLabel -> {"a", "b", "", "c"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "title", 
  Epilog -> {{(annotation[#[[1]], -8.0,25, #[[2]]] & /@ poi)}
    }]
```

The use of labels is due to the fact that the graphic is meant to be used with LaTeX. In this mwe, the point is being indicated with explicit reference to the function; in my applications it's actually necessary to specify it in this way. The desired output is something like this:

[image]

and then:

[image]

Comment: add the option `PlotRangeClipping -> False` in `Show`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rf = ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"];

Quiet @ rf[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 100}, 
   FrameStyle -> {{Blue, Red}, {Black, Black}}, BaseStyle -> 15], 
  Plot[100 x^4, {x, 0, 10}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log", Frame -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 10^6}, FrameStyle -> Red, PlotStyle -> Red], 
  "AxesSides" -> "TwoY", 
  FrameLabel -> {"a", "b", "", "c"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "title", 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  Epilog -> {Dashed, Gray, Line[{{0, 25}, {5, 25}, {5, 0}}], 
    Text[Style[Subscript[t, 1], 12], {5, 0}, {Center, Top}], 
    Text[Style[f[Subscript[t, 1]], 12], Offset[{-15, 7}, {0, 25}], {Right, Center}]}]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> ```
> 11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)
> ```