# Place Graphics outside PlotRange without using PlotRangeClipping set to False

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling

I want to place a `Text` (or some other Graphics object) outside the `PlotRange` using the `Epilog` option. I know that I can do this by adding some `ImagePadding` and using `PlotRangeClipping -> False` (see eg. [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/251333/epilog-outside-the-plotting-area)).

However, `PlotRangeClipping->False` is not an option for me, because in the final `Graphics` object I need to combine several plots using `Show` with a new `PlotRange`. The individual plots extend this range, and therefore the plots will leak out of the desired plot region.

Is there a way to place the Text outside the PlotRange without using `PlotRangeClipping -> False`?

As a minimal example to see the unwanted behavior I create two plots:

```
p1 = ListLinePlot[{{-1, 1}, {10, 3}}, PlotRange -> All];
p2 = ListLinePlot[{{1, 1}, {10, 10}}, PlotRange -> All];
```

and use Show to display both with the additional Text:

```
Show[{p1, p2}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 8}}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 ImagePadding -> {{All, 50}, {All, All}}, 
 Epilog -> Style[Text["A", Scaled[{1.1, 0.5}]], Red, Large]
]
```

[image: unwanted behavior due to PlotRangeClipping->False]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up with creating a `Rectangle` on which I placed the required elements. For the placement of the elements, I found it most convenient to specify absolute values for the width and height of the rectangle as well as the `ImageSize` of the plots.

First create the two plots:

```
p1 = ListLinePlot[{{-1, 1}, {10, 3}}, PlotRange -> All];
p2 = ListLinePlot[{{1, 1}, {10, 10}}, PlotRange -> All];
```

Then create a Graphics object that serves as a canvas:

```
widthCanvas = 300;
heightCanvas = 170;
canvas = Graphics[{
        White, 
        Rectangle[{0, 0}, {widthCanvas, heightCanvas}]
    },
    PlotRangePadding -> 0
];
```

Combine the two plots:

```
widthPlots = 250;
plotsCombined = Show[
    {p1, p2}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 8}}, 
    Frame -> True, 
    ImageSize -> widthPlots
]
```

Finally `Show` the canvas, add the `Text` and place the combined plots as an `Inset` in the `Epilog` option

```
Show[canvas, Epilog -> {
    Inset[plotsCombined, Offset[{15, 15}], Scaled[{0, 0}]],
    Style[Text["A", Scaled[{0.95, 0.5}]], Red, Large]
}]
```

[image: canvas]

PS: in this image, I used the background color `LightOrange` instead of `White` to visualize the canvas boundaries.